# What is the best form element styling library/plug-in (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms, styles

In the project I am working on at the moment form elements (like `<input>`,`<select>`,`<textarea>` etc)
must have non-standard 'look-n-feel'.

Which library or plugin (jQuery) can you recommend for this?

I have searched through some the available libraries, but did not find a library that suits my needs. All of them have 'real' - 'fake' element idea behid them.
The project has a lot of form elements created on-the-fly and injected into the DOM.

The main requirements are:

- Creation of 'fake' element/s on the fly.
- Ability to apply styles for one node or CSS selector (not the whole page).
- Non-intrusive events propagation between fake and real elements.
  (Fake element should respond to changes in real element and send events occuring on it to the corresponding real element
  like blur, focus, change, click. Library should take care about events propagation, not the code)
- It should be compatible with IE7 and upwards.
- Should have good documentation and flexible public API

I am struggling with one library and almost "adapted" it to the requirements but it lacks documentation and the licencing is unclear
as to whether I can modify it.

Thank you very much for the help!

Kind regards.

Comment: You can style form elements with CSS...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have a look at [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).  I believe it uses CSS to perform most of its tricks so you shouldn't need the concept of a delegate component (the real/fake thing) to get a slightly more polished look and feel.

Comment: watch out the browser support if you use bootstrap, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132331/bootstrap-versions-and-browser-compatibility

Comment: for instance, version 2.3.2 seems to support IE7+ http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.3.2/docs/#about but version 3.1.1 does not seem to be tested (or supported?) by IE<10 https://saucelabs.com/u/bootstrap

Comment: more regarding the support http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support , version 3.1.1 they say "On Windows, we support Internet Explorer 8-11"

Answer (score 5):

you may want to look into those (february 2014):

[uniformjs.com](http://uniformjs.com) - form elements styling (IE7+, chrome, safari, firefox)

[github.com/emblematiq/Niceforms](http://github.com/emblematiq/Niceforms) - form elements styling - (maybe?) sounds risky as no community, one commiter only (IE7+, Firefox2+, Safari3+, Opera9+, Chrome0.3+)

[github.com/harvesthq/chosen](http://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) and [harvesthq.github.io/chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen) - form select/dropdown box

[ivaynberg.github.io/select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2) - dropdown boxes (IE8+), it seems to have originated from Chosen.js (to be double checked)

[github.com/Robdel12/DropKick](http://github.com/Robdel12/DropKick) and [robdel12.github.io/DropKick](http://robdel12.github.io/DropKick) - form select/dropdown box

[github.com/gfranko/jQuery.selectBoxIt.js](http://github.com/gfranko/jQuery.selectBoxIt.js) - form select/dropdown box

[brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js) or [github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js](http://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js) - hybrid of a textbox and  box - useful for tagging, contact lists, country selectors, and so on

[arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable](http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable) - form checkboxes & radio buttons styling (IE7+, Chrome, Firefox, Safari & mobile browsers)

http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/ or https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input - tags

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) might be a good option too - [Use the Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) to only load the part of the library that you need, read more about [customizing Twitter bootstrap components](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#customizing)

Answer (score 4):

You can see this!

```
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms
```

Bootstrap has very and util things that can help you!!

Comment: Dang, you beat me by literally 2 seconds. :)

Answer (score 2):

I really like [jQtransform](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jqtransform): you just need to include jQuery library and plugin jqtransform

```
//required
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqtransform.min.js"></script>
```

**and then apply the transformations to all form**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    //find all form with class jqtransform and apply the plugin
    $("form").jqTransform();
});
</script>
```

**or to a specific form**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    //find all form with class jqtransform and apply the plugin
    $("form.jqtransform").jqTransform();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to style you input, select and textarea's you don't really need javascript to do that. That is all easily possible with normal css (change the borders, colors, background, rounded corners, etc..). Only older (IE) browsers will not be able to use rounded corners on your (form) elements.

If you also want to be able to style the dropdown of you select-element, you may need javascript, because that will not work in CSS.

From all the existing libraries I looked at I found jqTransform the easiest to work with (as mentioned earlier) because it delivers the 'cleanest' HTML replacements for you form elements. Which are all easy to style with css.

But, I have a few issues with jqTransform. For starters, it contains a bug that causes the onchance event on a select element not to fire, also it has no destroy/refresh option. So you won't be able to style new elements injected in a already styled form. For both these issues I have created workarounds to make it work. I found a fix for the onchange event (somewhere here on stackoverflow) and I also wrote an extra function to refresh a jqTransform element.

But, because of these issues and the fact that jqTransform hasn't been updated since 2009 I decided about a month ago to write my own jQuery plugin to handle this functionality for me.

It's called 'jQuery Mighty Form Styler' and it should work fine with jQuery 1.7 and above. At this point it only styles the select element, because other form elements can be styled with css. So why add load time to you page with unnecessary javascript? I'm planning to add radio and checkboxes too because styling them with just css is not that easy (and nog working in a lot of browsers).

It already does feature a refresh and destroy function to remove the fake elements or refresh the content of the fake elements.

You can get it at http://www.binkje.nl/mfs where you can also find the documentation. It's free for everybody to use. Although I do believe that you shouldn't style anything with javascript. That is something you should only do with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for styling for both desktop web and mobile - a responsive solution - take a look at [Mobiscroll Forms](https://mobiscroll.com/forms).

It ships with 13 distinctive controls from text inputs to alerts, notification and customizable sliders. You should be covered for your basic form needs and beyond.

Another thing to note is that the elements can be styled with the built-in themes - for iOS, Material, Windows, Web - and of course with CSS above that.

- The toolset can be downloaded from the [website](https://mobiscroll.com/forms).
- Demos can be
  seen [here](https://demo.mobiscroll.com/forms).
- If you prefer: [Github repo](https://github.com/acidb/mobiscroll/) and [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobiscroll-jquery).