# Bootstrap versions and browser compatibility

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser, internet-explorer-6

We are currently developing an application that will have to run on older corporate PCs that still have IE6 installed.

I have been looking around a bit, but I cannot find a clear answer for the following: is there a link where different bootstrap versions are paired to the corresponding supported browser versions?

For example:

```
Bootstrap 1.1 supports IE 6 and up, Chrome, FF, ...
Bootstrap 2.1 supports IE 7 and up, Chrome, FF, ...
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is the link to the official docs for Bootstrap versions: http://bootstrapdocs.com/

Looking at [Browser support for Bootstrap 1.1.0](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v1.1.0/docs/#about) it says Internet Explorer 7+. The docs for the earlier version v 1.0.0 (which was the first public release) doesn't even mention supported browsers. You can check if more recent version added support for IE6, but I don't think so. I also discourage using an old version at all.

If you can chose another framework I'd suggest [YAML](http://www.yaml.de/), it is actively maintained, well documented and supports IE6, too.

Comment: Why would you name your framework yaml... that's a human friendly data serialization standard for all programming languages.

Answer (score 18):

You can take look at [Website Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support).

Officially IE7 is not supported. IE8 and IE9 will be support.

Comment: That is true for bootstrap 3